# Error in assigning awk variable to bash variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Variable `b` has a string. Awk retrieves a substring which I want to assign to variable `c`. This is what I did:

```
#!/bin/bash
b=$(llsubmit multiple.cmd)
echo $b | c=$(awk '{
ret=match($0,".in.")
rwt=match($0,"\" has")
rqt=rwt-(ret+4)
subs=substr($0,(ret+4),rqt)
}')
```

... but I get a blank output for `echo $c`:

[image: 1]

Comment: Take a look at: [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Welcome to SO, thing is if you don't bother to spend time on your question's details it will be hard to imagine that people will spend time on that. please try to post samples of input and output and paste them in CODE TAGS in your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pipe into an assignment.

```
c=$(echo "$b" | awk '{
    ret=match($0,".in.")
    rwt=match($0,"\" has")
    rqt=rwt-(ret+4)
    subs=substr($0,(ret+4),rqt)
    }')
```

(Notice also the quoting around `$b`.)

But your Awk script looks rather complex. And it doesn't produce any output. Should it print something at the end? Without access to sample output from `llsubmit` this is mildly speculative, but I'm guessing something like this could work:

```
c=$(echo "b" | sed -n 's/.*\(\.in\.[^"]*\)" has .*/\1/p')
```

(Notice also the backslashes to make the dots match literally.)

You should properly then use double quotes in `echo "$c"` too (unless you are completely sure that the output cannot contain any shell metacharacters).

... And, of course, very often you don't want or need to store results in a variable in shell scripts if you can refactor your code into a pipeline.  Perhaps you are really looking for something like

```
llsubmit multiple.cmd |
sed -n 's/.*\(\.in\.[^"]\)" has .*/p' |
while read -r job; do
    : things with "$job"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question since you didn't provide sample input and expected output but is this what you're trying to do:

```
$ b='foo .in.bar has'
$ c="${b% has*}"
$ c="${c#*.in.}"
$ echo "$c"
bar
```

Comment: I'm guessing `llsubmit` could emit multiple lines? I found a wacky IBM site with some output examples.

Comment: If it did then the OPs `echo $b` would compress it all to 1 line so the substring functionality in the question is operating on a single line and hopefully he's tested THAT much at least and is happy with how that part of it works. idk, I only answered because there was already an answer posted otherwise I'd have waited for the [mcve].